# 小さく住んでいる meaning

Tags: grammar, meaning, translation

In my textbook I have a sentence 「私の町は小さく、住んでいる人は30万人以下です」
I have a couple of questions on this..
At first glance I thought this meant “living small” as in the opposite of “living large” but I can’t see a textbook using that kind of language?
Also why does this sentence use 2 は’s instead of 1 は and a が?

(Edit) Just realized the 小さく has a comma after it and since it’s written I’m assuming the 小さく means 小さくて、!

As for the double は part of anyone can help!

Feel free to use examples.
Thank you!!

Comment: Could you provide a screenshot or a reference to the source material? It doesn't sound very Japanese at first glance, so maybe context can help.

Comment: @JansthcirlU hey sorry, I re-read it and realized my mistake. Any thoughts on the second issue?

Comment: To prevent further confusion, perhaps you could also edit the original sentence. As for the second 「は」, I think it introduces the topic 「（私の町に）住んでいる人」but I can't quite put my finger on it. I'll look into it a bit further before posting an answer.

Comment: @JansthcirlU okay thank you!

Comment: 30万人? That’s a huge city, not a small town!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 私の町は小さく、

The first sentence uses「は」to introduce a new topic, with the added emphasis that it concerns the speaker's home town specifically. As you pointed out yourself, the construction 「小さく、」is a different way to write 「小さくて、」which helps the listener prepare for more information related to 「私の町」.

> 住んでいる人は30万人以下です。

For the second part of the sentence, the topic becomes 「（私の町に）住んでいる人」. However, the particle「は」is used over「が」because it concerns information that's already shared between the speaker and the listener (i.e. information *about* the speaker's town). In [this answer](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/78335/39516) I try to explain the nuance between 「は」and「が」when they're used after the subject of a sentence.

Another possibly confusing aspect about this sentence could be the fact that 「人」which is generally taught to mean "person" or "people," suddenly refers to a population. In English, you might expect a more explicit wording such as "the number of people" as opposed to just "people."

The thing is that「住んでいる人」does indeed refer to *people who live in my town*, but that the second 「人」in「３０万人」is the **counter** for people, something that doesn't really exist in English. So what you would express as "the number of people" in English, is actually engrained in the usage of a counter in Japanese.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer!!