# Use of は in 「確認はされていない」

Tags: nuances, verbs, particle-は

I think the quote

> 「確認はされていない」

translates to "It hasn't been confirmed yet". However, the use of は is leaving me a bit uncertain. As far as I know, 確認 can be used either a name or a する-verb, and 確認する would be to confirm. In that sense, I'd expect instead to see

> 「確認されていない」

する-verbs can also take the を particle, so I'd also understand

> 「確認をされていない」

Is は used here, instead of the optional を, to emphasise 確認? If so, can this happen with other する-verbs?

Comment: は is used here to emphasize, that's true. も can also be used. But I have never seen the "optional を" used when する is in its passive form.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using は instead of を here, the differences?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/77961/using-%e3%81%af-instead-of-%e3%82%92-here-the-differences/78335#78335)

Comment: Sounds like the「は」here is used to make a distinction, i.e. there is a rumour or suspicion but it hasn't been confirmed yet. And yes, it can happen with other verbs: [〜はされていない examples](https://ejje.weblio.jp/sentence/content/%22%E3%81%AF%E3%81%95%E3%82%8C%E3%81%A6%E3%81%84%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84%22).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically speaking, は in a negative sentence specifies what's negated. (Note that it's practically not necessarily the case depending on verbal emphasis.)

- 今日は勉強をしない (You may study another day.)
- 今日、勉強はしない (You may do other things.)

Practically, however, people often use は just because the predicate is negative. So, although it depends on usages, there's no major difference among 確認はされてない、確認をされてない and 確認されてない. If any, the は version could imply that the speaker is sure about it while not confirmed, or so.